# Getting value before the dot

Tags: javascript

I have the value **56.024096385542165** and I want the number before the dot. (In this case, it's **56**).

How can I do this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do

`parseInt(yournumber, 10)`

Comment: Do not forget, that `parseInt()` requires first parameter to be string. If you are using linters, there will be a warning. So better way is `parseInt(String(yournumber), 10)`.

Comment: const num = 14.56789;

const beforeDecimal = Math.trunc(num);
console.log(beforeDecimal); // ️ 14